# Why is "sudo touch <<some file name>>" needed before installing certain packages?

Tags: plugins, gtalk

I'm asked to do "sudo touch /etc/default/google-talkplugin" prior to installing 'google-talk plugin' in their installation  instructions

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more info so that even people who don't know what a google-talkplugin is may have a chance to answer. E.g. does the `sudo touch ...` fail and you are curious? What do you try to achieve? All I can see is a symptom.

Comment: +1 @aquaherd - Yes the question needs a little bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would need to know where you got that information or what site says to run that in order to install but I would guess the following:

1. Since `sudo touch` simply creates a file this might mean that the app that needs to install would do a boolean check on the file. If the file exists then it continues doing the install or any other process. If not, it stops with maybe a warning.
2. If the app can not create the file by itself (Either for security reasons or permissions), then it might need your help in creating the file first in order to be able to edit the file later on.

Now, going directly to the Google Talk Plugin, it is my understanding that having the file `/etc/default/google-talkplugin` means to the google plugin that it should NOT add the google plugin repository, saving you from either a future update that may be broken for some apps, or letting you update the plugin manually every time an update appears.

This means that when you install the Google Audio/Video chat plugin, it automatically adds it's repository to Ubuntu. In the case you do not want the plugin to add the repository, then simply execute the line in question:

`sudo touch /etc/default/google-talkplugin`

I personally never add that file, I like having some stuff automatically fetch and updated.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Luis Alvarado... Your answer is helpful..

I'm sorry that I haven't visited your answer (also your +1) till this moment

Comment: Edited question as suggested by you and Mr. @aquaherd

Comment: @ShashankSabniveesu if Luis' answer was helpful, you can [mark it as your accepted answer](http://www.askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (if it is indeed so) by clicking the grey check box to the left of it.